# Systemd: stop service before suspend, restart after resume

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I have a systemd service that runs a background daemon (`xflux`) from the user session manager.

When I suspend and resume my computer, it messes up `xflux`'s time reckoning; I have to manually issue `systemctl --user restart xflux` to fix it.

How can I tell the service to automatically stop before suspend, and start after resume? (I found an answer that automatically runs a given service on resume, but this isn't quite what I want.)

Answer (score 5):

You can put an executable file in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` and it will be run on suspend with the 2 args `pre` and `suspend`, and again after resume with `post` and `suspend`. The systemd [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html) says this is a hack.

---

To use a systemd Unit, see my later [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620151/119298) to a similar question.

Comment: Any chance you know how to apply this to user services?

Answer (score 1):

Old thread - however, I stumbled over a similar situation.
The requested code snippet should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    USER=username
    post)
    su - $USER --shell=/bin/sh -c '
            export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u);
            systemctl --user restart xflux
            '
    ;;
esac
```