# Stop python script before suspend, start it again after resume

Tags: linux, arch-linux, python

So I have a python script that I want to start at startup of computer, stop at suspend and restart when I wake up my system, how can we do so?
and can we do it without systemd?

Comment: Creating a `systemd` service would be the easiest way to go about this. Can you add some info on why you want to avoid it?

Comment: what OS are you running? Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620151/357628 for the above @Haxiel's suggestion.